# Silverstripe i18n collecting translations in the templates only creates en.yaml?

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am building a site that uses ar and en languages, and according to the silverstripe docs [here](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/i18n/#usage-in-template-files), I did the text collection process and went successful. but only one en.yaml file is created in the lang folder in my current theme. there should be another ar.yaml file!.

here's my _config.php file:

```
<?php

global $project;
$project = 'mysite';

FulltextSearchable::enable();

global $databaseConfig;
$databaseConfig = array(
    'type' => 'MySQLDatabase',
    'server' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'dbuser',
    'password' => '123',
    'database' => 'cont_learning_2',
    'path' => ''
);

// Set the site locale
i18n::set_locale('ar_EG');

Director::set_environment_type('dev');

if(!Director::isDev()) {
    // log errors and warnings
    SS_Log::add_writer(new SS_LogFileWriter('../silverstripe-errors-warnings.log'), SS_Log::WARN, '<=');

    // or just errors
    SS_Log::add_writer(new SS_LogFileWriter('../silverstripe-errors.log'), SS_Log::ERR);

    // or notices (e.g. for Deprecation Notifications)
    SS_Log::add_writer(new SS_LogFileWriter('../silverstripe-errors-notices.log'), SS_Log::NOTICE);
}

Security::setDefaultAdmin('admin','admin');



// multi-language configuration - translatable module
Translatable::set_default_locale('ar_EG');
Translatable::set_allowed_locales(array(
    'ar_EG',
    'en_US',
));
SiteTree::add_extension('Translatable');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using https://github.com/Zauberfisch/silverstripe-better-i18n you are able to create and update different languages in one task. You can install it with composer as a development-only requirement.

I run it like

```
http://localhost/dev/tasks/BetterI18nTextCollectorTask?module=mysite,themes/my-theme&targetlocale=de,en
```

to create german and english yml files in *mysite* and *themes/my-theme*.

It will create a bunch of items prefixed with double underscore (as pseudo comments) and also the default keys for your database fields.

Comment: it works great, I needed to delete those double underscores. thanks you saved me a lot of time :)

Answer (score 2):

The text-collector task isn't aware of the possible locales your installation will/can have. So it basically just collects all strings and puts them in a default yml file.

If you have an `en.yml` file, copy it as `ar.yml`, make sure it starts with `ar:` instead of `en:` and translate all text to Arabic.

Comment: I copied it as ar.yaml and changed first line to `ar:`. now the site takes the arabic translation on both locales (both english and arabic versions of the page!).

Comment: Your `en.yml` file needs to start with `en:` and contain english translations. Your `ar.yml` file needs to start with `ar:` and contain the arabic translations… have you verified that this is the case?

Comment: yes I made sure of that and now it is working, thanks.@bummzack